# How to run a code containing loop on one click in shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Hi I'm trying to run a set of code by one click through interactive shiny app.
I'm relatively newer to Shiny and having confusion in running one click code. Below is the dummy code...

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

titlePanel("Pricing Change"),
sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    h3("Select Features"),
    selectInput("sku","Select  SKU ",
                choices = as.character(main_file$Alternatives) ,
                selectize = T),
    .
    .
    .
    .

    actionButton("do", "Click Me")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tableOutput("ckt"),
     )))



shinyServer(function(input,output){
sku5 <- reactive({input$sku}) 
main_file$Alternatives <- as.character(main_file$Alternatives) 

#Getting utilities for interpolar price points
interpolar_pp <- reactive({
aa <- spline_plot(main_file,sku5())
return(aa)
})

ck_tab <- data.frame()

output$ckt <- renderTable({ input$do 
isolate(
for(z in 1:nrow(interpolar_pp())){

elas_matrix[elas_matrix$bought_sku==sku5(),sku5()] <- interpolar_pp()[z,2]
el_sum <- apply(elas_matrix[,-1],1,sum)
elas_matrix$total_cross_els <- el_sum


#Adding cross price elasticities with feature utilities
Optimizer_panel<-sqldf("select a.*, b.total_cross_els as cross_els
                       from Optim_panel as a 
                       left join
                       elas_matrix as b
                       on a.Alternatives = b.bought_sku")



Optimizer_panel$Total_util <- as.numeric(Optimizer_panel$Feature_Util + 
Optimizer_panel$cross_els )

#Ranking skus in each panel based on total utility
Optimizer_panel$Total_util <- Optimizer_panel$Total_util*(-1)
Optimizer_panel <- setDT(Optimizer_panel )
Optimizer_panel[, rank := frank(Total_util),
                by = list(RespID)]

#setting counter for selected sku as Top sku
Optimizer_panel <- as.data.frame(Optimizer_panel)
sku1_top <- nrow(Optimizer_panel[Optimizer_panel$Alternatives==sku5() & 
Optimizer_panel$rank==1,])
.
ck_tab[z,"Price"] <- interpolar_pp()[z,1]
ck_tab[z,"Count"] <- sku1_top
}
ck_tab })
```

There are two issues I'm facing

```
1.I'm subsetting a dataframe by the use of rownumber.
Eg: Multiple skus are selected by user on app
sku <- reactive({input$sku})

#I wanna subset all those rows where my_file$sku is in reactive list created 
above
I generally use 
rnum <- which(my_file$sku %in%  sku)
req_set <- myfile[rnum,] in general R

#Similarly I'm trying to do in shiny server, I created a reactive rnum() and 
then trying to subset, on this it throwing an error: argument 1 (type 
'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'


2. In my app I'm getting action button but my code is not running  (I have 
tested my code in general R and its working fine there).
```

Please suggest remedy for my issue. I'm having issue in inculcating reactive values in my on click code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please do not ask 2 questions in a single post

Comment: To 1st question, try `sku5 <- reactive({my_file$sku %in% input$sku }).

Comment: Hi Cpak! Thanks for suggestion. But it's not working , it's still giving same error:argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'. .. in above code sku5() is a reactive list containing rows address that I wanna subset. What's  the general practice of subsetting dataset using row address (row address changes with user feed)? Thanks!